# Covering system of congruences

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

I have a really beautiful problem from my teacher but I havent solved it yet. I will appreciate any hint from you guys.

Assume that $T=\{(q_1,r_1);(q_2,r_2);...,(q_i,r_i)\}$ is a set of pairs of positive integers $(q_j,r_j)$. A set $A$ of positive integers is covered by $T$ if for every positive integer $t \in A$, there exists a pair $(q_j,r_j)$ belongs to $T$ such that $t \equiv r_j \pmod{q_j}$. 
Given $k$ be an positive integer and $p_1,p_2,...,p_k$ be prime numbers. Prove that for if $c_1,c_2,...,c_k$ are positive integers then:

a. The set $A=\{1,2,...,(k+1).2^k\}$ cannot be covered by the set $T'=\{p_1,c_1),(p_2,c_2),...,(p_k,c_k)\}$

b. The set $A'=\{1,2,...,2^k\}$ cannot be covered by the set $T'=\{(p_1,c_1),(p_2,c_2),...,(p_k,c_k)\}$
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know the Chinese Remainder Theorem? At first glance, it looks as if it might be relevant here.

Comment: Yes I do. At first I tried to use CRT here but I think it's not enough.

Comment: Ah...why don't you tell us what you've tried/done so far, and then we can help you out in a better-informed way.